After build, the app doesn't load <Slot />
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import { store, persistor } from "./(redux)/store";

import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import { Redirect, Slot, SplashScreen, useRouter } from "expo-router";

import Toast, { BaseToast } from "react-native-toast-message";

import Header from "../components/Header";
import { View } from "react-native";

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function Layout() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <SafeAreaView>
          <Header />
          <Slot />
          <Toast topOffset={150} config={toastConfig} visibilityTime={1000} />
        </SafeAreaView>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}

const toastConfig = {
  /*
    Overwrite 'success' type,
    by modifying the existing `BaseToast` component
  */
  success: (props) => (
    <BaseToast
      {...props}
      style={{ borderLeftColor: "#4BB543" }}
      contentContainerStyle={{ paddingHorizontal: 15 }}
      text1Style={{
        fontSize: 15,
        fontWeight: "400",
      }}
    />
  ),
};

I have this code using Expo, but the problem seems to be the Slot component, because if i try to console.log something in it, it doesn't show anything.
I tried to console.log something in it, it doesn't show anything.

There are different ways to about the solution for this, but I will suggest you create a file called ProjectProviders.tsx for example and have all your providers and other configurations there. Also make sure that file takes children so that you can wrap the slot in the root provider this way
<ProjectProvider>
  <Slot />
<ProjectProvider>

I hope this helps

Sadly, it does not. I think it is a deeper problem, even if i'm deleting all the code is still doesn't work. I think i will create a new test project to see what is the problem.

I am currently building an app with the new structure of expo router on SDK51, if it is possible to create a new project with the new structure, everything should work fine

It finally worked, after creating a new project and moving all the code into the new project.
